# how to form a new variable to count the intervals of time

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
 xxx <- data.frame(
  time = c(0.001,0.002,0.003,0.308,0.309,0.310,0.311,0.405,0.406,0.407,0.408,0.201,0.202,0.405),
  id = as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)),
  n = c(3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,1),
  x = c(10,12,16,3,5,9,11,51,56,59,80,1,2,9)
)
```

I want to form a new variable (interval), to have this: 
for each id, every time start a new interval (time), the variable "interval"  changes the value.

```
time     id  n  x  interval 
0.001    1   3  10    1
0.002    1   3  12    1
0.003    1   3  16    1
0.308    1   4  3     2
0.309    1   4  5     2
0.310    1   4  9     2
0.311    1   4  11    2
0.405    1   4  51    3
0.406    1   4  56    3
0.407    1   4  59    3
0.408    1   4  80    3
0.201    2   2  1     1
0.202    2   2  2     1
0.405    2   1  9     2
```

and now I want select the interval that contains min(x) for each id, to have:

```
time     id  n  x  interval 

0.308    1   4  3     2
0.309    1   4  5     2
0.310    1   4  9     2
0.201    2   2  1     1
0.202    2   2  2     1
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the rule to distinguish `time`?

Comment: What is min(Fx) ?

Comment: The min(x) for each id will be only a single element in x and not 3, 5, 9 for id 1

Comment: @sotos, the data frame is the result of differents operations, there isn't a rule on time.

Comment: @akrun I want all interval that contains min (x)

Comment: so how are we supposed to group time to create the intervals? This `cumsum(c(1, (abs(diff(round(xxx$time, 1))) >= 0.1)*1))` seems to be working (ungrouped) but it's a guess...

Answer (score 0):

We may need some threshold

```
library(data.table)
dt <-  setDT(xxx)[,  interval := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(time) > 0.05)), id]
i1 <- dt[,  .I[x < 10 & .N > 1], .(id, interval)]$V1
dt[i1]
#    time id n x interval
#1: 0.308  1 4 3        2
#2: 0.309  1 4 5        2
#3: 0.310  1 4 9        2
#4: 0.201  2 2 1        1
#5: 0.202  2 2 2        1
```